# How do we parse and generate App Engine URL-Safe Datastore Keys in the Google Cloud API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We have some URL-safe Datastore Keys that were created using in the AppEngine API, for example `agx0cmFkZW9zLXRlc3RyHQsSEHVzZXIvTGVnYWxFbnRpdHkYgICAgIDu1AkM`

These are parsed correctly in the AppEngine API, using `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.stringToKey(key)`

However, in the Google Cloud API,  `com.google.cloud.datastore.Key.fromUrlSafe(key)`  always generates a parsing error as below.

Perhaps the URL-Safe string formats of the Google Cloud API was changed incompatibly, but we do need to be able to parse and also to generate the old format.

The code for this is available in the App Engine API distribution. It de/serializes a ProtoBuf *Reference* object.

Ultimately this is a string-parsing task with no deep dependency on the libraries, so it should be possible to do with a simple code snippet and without any code specific to the App Engine API.

How can we parse and generate such key strings using the Google Cloud API?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse key
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.Key.fromUrlSafe(Key.java:205)
...
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$ParseException: 1:61: Expected "{".
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Tokenizer.parseException(TextFormat.java:1064)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Tokenizer.consume(TextFormat.java:750)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Parser.skipFieldMessage(TextFormat.java:1770)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Parser.mergeField(TextFormat.java:1528)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Parser.mergeField(TextFormat.java:1439)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Parser.merge(TextFormat.java:1423)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Parser.merge(TextFormat.java:1342)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat.merge(TextFormat.java:1221)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.Key.fromUrlSafe(Key.java:200)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: There seems to be a [bug report](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1357) for this, but unfortunately it doesn't provide a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

in the absence of a fix to the bug report that @snakecharmerb found, could you not base64 decode the string and tease out the pieces that you need to construct a Key via the [`Key.newBuilder` method](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/Key.java#L220)?

Certainly not ideal, but would get you around the issue.

Comment: Yes, doing all that is exactly what we need: figuring out what variety of Base64 and how to tease out those pieces. We also need to know how to *generate* such a format.

Comment: The hard part is that, after base64  decoding, you get  a byte array which is a protobuf-serialized object. Deserializing the protobuf object without access to the protobuf  code for the specific  class is the hard part. And in fact, you can get access to  that class (in binary form) in the appengine API, but the goal of this question is to avoid that API.